# How to work with Scala in vagrant box spark installation?

Tags: scala, installation, apache-spark, vagrant

I installed spark using instructions provided at https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS100.1x/1T2015/courseware/d1f293d0cb53466dbb5c0cd81f55b45b/920d3370060540c8b21d56f05c64bdda/

This lets me run jupyter ipython notebook which provides a pyspark interface on localhost browser. But I wanted to learn more about Scala.

What could be the best way to run Scala using this vagrant based installation. Is there a way that I can run some sort of IDE with this vagrant config. The best would be if I am able to use some notebook like interface to Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run Scala from jupyter ipython notebook interface. Select New-Terminal. Then, type this command "spark-shell". Scala API window will open.
I hope that will help you